# All the vectors interior to a parallelogram

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider two vectors $a$ and $b$, then their linear combinations
$c_1a + c_2b$
where $c_1+c_2=1$ and $c_1, c_2\ge 0$.

We clearly get the line segment $ab$.
Next I have two questions.

---

1) Is there a nice expression to represent ***all*** the vectors *interior* to the ***triangle*** formed by the vectors $a$, $b$ and the *origin*?
(I know one ugly looking expression : $c_3*[c_1a + c_2b]$)

2) How to get an expression to represent all the vectors interior to the ***parallelogram*** formed by the vectors $a,b$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to both of your questions is a [convex combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination).

For your triangle: take point $a$, $b$, and the origin $c=(0,0)$, then all points
$$\alpha_1 a+\alpha_2 b+\alpha_3 c$$
lie in the triangle provided $\alpha_i\geq 0$ and $\sum \alpha_i=1$

Similarly, the vertices of the parallelogram are $c=(0,0)$, $a$, $b$, and $a+b$, and all points in the parallelogram are given by
$$\alpha_1 a+\alpha_2 b+\alpha_3 c+\alpha_4 (a+b)$$
again with $\alpha_i\geq 0$ and $\sum \alpha_i=1$

Comment: Okay I'll lookup convex combination. Before that if I may ask a quick question... With triangle, it seems you're just doing $\alpha_1 a  +\alpha_2 b$ where $\alpha_i \ge 0$ and  $\sum\alpha_i \le 1$ right? Thank you so much for the fast response:)

Comment: Yes, but note that this generalizes to the case where the third vertex $c$ is not the origin.

Comment: Ah right, if the triangle has none of its vertices at origin...  i'll read some convex combination and get back thanks again you're awesome :D

Answer (score 1):

For the triangle,

$$(1-\lambda_a-\lambda_b)0+\lambda_a a+\lambda_b b=\lambda_a a+\lambda_b b$$

where $\lambda_a, \lambda_b \ge 0$ and $\lambda_a+\lambda_b \le 1$.

For the parallelogram formed by $0, a, b, c=a+b$.

\begin{align}(1-\lambda_a-\lambda_b-\lambda_c)0+\lambda_a a+\lambda_b b+\lambda_cc&=\lambda_a a+\lambda_b b+\lambda_cc\\
&=(\lambda_a+\lambda_c)a+(\lambda_b+\lambda_c)b\end{align}

where $\lambda_a, \lambda_b, \lambda_c \ge 0$ and $\lambda_a+\lambda_b+\lambda_c \le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The vectors strictly in the interior of the parallelogram with vertices at $0$, $a$, $b$ and $a+b$ are

$c_1a+c_2b$

where $0 < c_1 < 1$ and $0 < c_2 < 1$.

If you include vectors on the boundary of the parellogram then the constraints are $0 \le c_1 \le 1$ and $0 \le c_2 \le 1$.